# How to access array inside array of object in Angular7?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am using **Angular7** and have a custom class which contains a number and an array of string.

```
export class Page {
constructor(id: number, keywords: string[]) {}
}
```

Now i created an array of this object in my component and intialised it.

```
import {Page} from '../page';
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
 pages: Page [];
 constructor() { }
 ngOnInit() {
 this.pages = [
  {id:'1', Keywords:['abc', 'bca','klj']},
  {id:'2', Keywords:['asas', 'aaa']},
  {id:'3', Keywords:['dasd', 'asd']}
  ];
  consol.log(this.pages[0].keywords);
  consol.log(this.pages[0].id);
 }
}
```

I want to access the `id`, and keywords array, but this code shows compilation error saying:

> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Page' and Property 'keywords'
>   does not exist on type 'Page'.

Comment: In `page.ts`, replace the code with: `export interface Page { id: string, keywords: string[] }`. then take care to the case of `keywords`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. But Why can't I use it as a class?

Comment: You can. Then you have to use the constructor: `this.pages = [new Page(1, ["a", "b"]), new Page(2, ["c", "d"])]`. Then in the Page's constructor, you must keep the parameters as properties by adding the `public` accessor: `constructor(public id: number, public keywords: string[]) {}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really a problem of beginner but… Here are the solutions:

## Using an interface

Define the interface:

```
export interface Page {
  id: number
  keywords: string[]
}
```

Then, use it:

```
this.pages = [
  { id: 1, keywords: ['a', 'b'] },
  { id: 2, keywords: ['c', 'd' }
]
```

## Using a class

Define the class:

```
export class Page {
  constructor(public id: number, public keywords: string[]) {}
}
```

Then, use it:

```
this.pages = [
  new Page(1, ['a', 'b']),
  new Page(2, ['c', 'd'])
]
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you are initilizing `this.pages`, with `id` as a **string** and with `keywords` as a array of **string**.

So you have to define an interface `Page`:

```
export interface Page {
  id: string;
  keywords: string[];
}
```

and use it like that, changing `Keywords` to `keywords`:

```
this.pages = [
  {id: '1', keywords:['abc', 'bca','klj']},
  {id: '2', keywords:['asas', 'aaa']},
  {id: '3', keywords:['dasd', 'asd']}
];
```

If you want the `id` attribute as a number, go like that:

```
export interface Page {
  id: number;
  keywords: string[];
}
and use it like that, changing Keywords to keywords:

this.pages = [
  {id: 1, keywords:['abc', 'bca','klj']},
  {id: 2, keywords:['asas', 'aaa']},
  {id: 3, keywords:['dasd', 'asd']}
];
```

If you want a **class** instead of an **interface**, look at @Paleo answer.